# ManyToOne MyBatis framework

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

My account does not hold list of balance in db it just has the field, so the idea is that when controller get called (createAccount) it also creates  and  i did it as a separate table in db , so now i am trying to get all the balances related to account and balances still returns as null. Would appreciate any help here

```
   @Select("Select accountId,customerId from account where accountId=#{accountId}")
    @Results(value = { @Result(property = "accountId", column = "accountId"), @Result(property = "customerId", column = "customerId"),
            @Result(property = "balances", javaType = List.class, column = "accountId", many = @Many(select = "getBalances"))

    })
    Optional<Account> getAccount(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Select("select currency,balanceId,accountId,amount from balance where accountId=#{accountId}")
    List<Balance> getBalances(Long accountId);


public class Account {

@Id
private Long accountId;

@Column("country")
private String country;

@Column("customerId")
private Long customerId;

List<Balance> balances;
```

Here is a little tricky , i am new to my batis so trying to find my way around it to do exactly what i need and it works except when i am trying to getaccount that should display everything including balances

I am basically first checking if the account exist if not i am creating the account then I am getting list of currencies from the request and building List of balances including the initial amount and also filling it with account id that gets generated.

```
 public Account create(AccountCreateRequest request) {
    Optional<Long> customerId = accountMapper.checkIfCustomerExist(request.getCustomerId());

    if (customerId.isEmpty()) {
        Account account = Account.builder().customerId(request.getCustomerId()).country(request.getCountry()).build();
        accountMapper.saveAccount(account);
        List<Balance> balances = request.getCurrencies().stream().map(currency -> Balance.builder()
                .currency(currency)
                .amount(BigDecimal.ZERO)
                .build()).map(b -> b.setAccountId(account.getAccountId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        balances.forEach(accountMapper::saveBalance);
        account.setBalances(balances);
        return account;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Account already exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please enable TRACE level logging and add the output of the query/mapping part to the question. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) for how to configure. If you are using Spring Boot, just adding `logging.level.pkg.of.your.mappers=TRACE` to application.properties may be sufficient (replace 'pkg.of.your.mappers' with the actual package FQN).

Comment: Check out the following, looks like you're missing the `column` attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568779/mybatis-one-to-many-values-not-set-for-mapped-column